# Rednder js in angular component

Tags: typescript, angular6

I used this styles for my page

> https://www.carbondesignsystem.com/components/accordion/code

I followed the developer instruction to start work with Carbon styles.
Then I insert "Accordion" code inside my page, looks like javascript doesn't work, because accordion doesn't display information inside "Section 1" and others sections.

> https://i.stack.imgur.com/HzMuV.jpg

How can I get it working?

> app.component.html

```
 <ul data-accordion class="bx--accordion">
  <li data-accordion-item class="bx--accordion__item">
    <button class="bx--accordion__heading" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pane1">
    <svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="will-change: transform;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bx--accordion__arrow" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M11 8l-5 5-.7-.7L9.6 8 5.3 3.7 6 3z"></path></svg>
     <div class="bx--accordion__title">Section 1 title</div>
    </button>
    <div id="pane1" class="bx--accordion__content">
     <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
  <li data-accordion-item class="bx--accordion__item">
   <button class="bx--accordion__heading" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="pane2">
     <svg focusable="false" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" style="will-change: transform;" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" class="bx--accordion__arrow" width="16" height="16" viewBox="0 0 16 16" aria-hidden="true"><path d="M11 8l-5 5-.7-.7L9.6 8 5.3 3.7 6 3z"></path></svg>
     <div class="bx--accordion__title">Section 2 title</div>
   </button>
    <div id="pane2" class="bx--accordion__content">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna
    aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</p>
    </div>
  </li>
 </ul>
```

> app.components.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Modal } from 'carbon-components';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss']
})
export class AppComponent {
title = 'carbone-st';
}
```

> style.scss

```
 @import '../node_modules/carbon-components/scss/globals/scss/s-tyles.scss';
```

> app.module.ts

```
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { NgModule } from '@angular/core';
import { ButtonModule } from "../../node_modules/carbon-components-angular";

import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { Modal } from 'carbon-components';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
  AppComponent
 ],
  imports: [
   BrowserModule,
   AppRoutingModule,
   ButtonModule
  ],
   providers: [],
   bootstrap: [AppComponent]
  })
 export class AppModule { }
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to use a vanilla javascript accordion from `carbon-components`.

While that *should* work, it also looks like you're using `carbon-components-angular` that comes with an angular version of accordion.

You could use it by adding `AccordionModule` to your app module and then put some `ibm-accordion-item`s in `ibm-accordion`.

Example from [demo](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/accordion--basic):

```html
<ibm-accordion>
    <ibm-accordion-item title="Section 1 title" (selected)="selected($event)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \
    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore \
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</ibm-accordion-item>
    <ibm-accordion-item title="Section 2 title" (selected)="selected($event)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \
    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore \
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</ibm-accordion-item>
    <ibm-accordion-item title="Section 3 title" (selected)="selected($event)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \
    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore \
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</ibm-accordion-item>
    <ibm-accordion-item title="Section 4 title" (selected)="selected($event)">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, \
    consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore \
    et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation \
    ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.</ibm-accordion-item>
</ibm-accordion>
```

More detailed info in [documentation](https://angular.carbondesignsystem.com/?path=/story/accordion--documentation).